# WPF dashboard design (with caliburn mvvm framework)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn

I'm beginner in WPF technology early I wrote only Windows Forms apps.

I have some troubles with designing dasboard on WPF.
I want make dashboard with widgets support. User can resize and move widget on dashboard.

I create dashboard view with this XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="Items">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <customUserControls:DashboardCanvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Where `customUserControls:DashboardCanvas` is overriden `Canvas` class with controls moving support.

Yea all works fine in ViewModel of dashboard on initialize I write next:

```
Items.Add(IoC.Get<Widget1ViewModel>());
Items.Add(IoC.Get<Widget2ViewModel>());
Items.Add(IoC.Get<Widget3ViewModel>());
```

All 3 widgets appears on the canvas in the `ListBox` but I want to controll items in one place. I can't access to the `<ContentControl />` from the `DashboardCanvas` class for, example, control resizing and manage intersection widgets.

I know this is design issue but I don't know what components I need to use for reach the result.

Can you advice how I can implement the dashboard with funclions declared above?
Thanks.

**UPD**: where is my `DashboardViewModel`

```
 internal class DashboardViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive
    {
        public DashboardViewModel()
        {
            Items.Add(IoC.Get<SalesWidgetViewModel>());
            Items.Add(IoC.Get<ActualDateViewModel>());
            Items.Add(IoC.Get<CommonStatsViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your `ViewModel` code?

Comment: @arcticwhite hi! I updated the main post.

Comment: If will be honest I partly solve my problem. I use `ItemsControl` instead `ListBox` and I can get `ContentControl`  from the `Canvas`. But I feel architecture problems in my solution.

Comment: You'll need to post your code where you resize or manage intersections of your widgets, since I don't know how did you implement that features.